# Input and Div Matching Heights

Tags: html, css, input, height

I am trying to get the height and width of a Div to match the height and width of an Input field.

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1kv70eg1/

```css
#outerDivOne, #outerDivTwo {
  height: 4em;
  width: 20em;
  border:solid blue 1px;
}
#onTop, #needSameWidth {
  text-align: center;
  border: solid #333333 1px;
  font-size: .9em;
  width: 5em;
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: 3%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  vertical-align: center;
}

#onRight, #needSameHeight {
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid #333333 1px;
  font-size: .9em;
  width: 5em;
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: 3%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  vertical-align: center;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id='outerDivOne'>
  <input type='text' id='onTop' placeholder='whatever'/>
  <div id="needSameWidth"><output>Test</output></div>
</div>

<div id='outerDivTwo'>
  <input type='text' id='onRight' placeholder='whatever'/>
  <div id="needSameHeight"><output>Test</output></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to provide explicit values for `margin` and `padding`. In your case they are default (non-zero), which skews your layout.

```css
#outerDivOne, #outerDivTwo {
  height: 4em;
  width: 20em;
  border:solid blue 1px;
}

#onTop, #needSameWidth {
  text-align: center;
  border: solid #333333 1px;
  font-size: .9em;
  width: 5em;
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: 3%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  vertical-align: center;
  padding: 0em;
  margin: 0em;
}

#onRight, #needSameHeight {
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid #333333 1px;
  font-size: .9em;
  width: 5em;
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: 3%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  vertical-align: center;
  float: left;
  padding: 0em;
  margin: 0em;
}
```

```html
<div id='outerDivOne'>
  <input type='text' id='onTop' placeholder='whatever'/>
  <div id="needSameWidth"><output>Test</output></div>
</div>

<div id='outerDivTwo'>
  <input type='text' id='onRight' placeholder='whatever'/>
  <div id="needSameHeight"><output>Test</output></div>
</div>
```

I'd also recommend checking out the *CSS Reset* approach to reduce such annoyances: https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done any experiments, but I see neither of your rulesets have margin or padding settings. I'd look at those.

Comment: Thanks for the help.